# Is Google's Protocol Buffer viable for the serialisation of game data?

Tags: client-server, data-structure, databases

Simple yes it is suitable, no it is not suitable for communications between game clients and/or server clients.  Also is it suitable for serialising and storing game data or is a more customisable, minimisable solution recommended.

Comment: What is your definition of suitable?

Comment: Yes, it is suitable.  Other suitable options are binary or JSON.  I find Protobufs easiest to deal with for serialization and deserialization.  What do you mean by storing game data?  You need to use your game server to keep track of the game data in memory, and dump it to a database when done with it, or just get rid of it if you don't want to save it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is suitable, though perhaps not ideal.

First, do note that ProtoBufs are no longer state of the art in its class. Consider [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/), [Fast Buffers](http://www.eprosima.com/index.php/products-all/eprosima-fast-buffers), or [Flat Buffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/). I'm personally a fan of Flat Buffers these days, but I'm sure there's already something even better out there; this is hardly a "solved" problem.

For serializing game data, you have several (competing) goals and you have several different use cases. Protobufs is not ideal, but it certainly does work. Even for networking, despite your supposition; I've used it for the network packet format in a (non-realtime) MMO for instance.

### Source Format

Here we're talking about the format that content is authored in. We might also be talking about intermediate formats (e.g. the raw source may be some model editor's native format but we also need an intermediate format that the engine or asset pipeline knows how to work with).

1. Ease of debugging, though not necessarily ease of editing.
2. Easy to merge with standard merge tools and source control tools by designers or even artists.
3. Easy to transform and update as the engine evolves and the data needed to be stored in source assets changes.
4. Lots of tools to manipulate the data for scripting, testing, etc.

I honestly find XML to be the best choice for most types of data here. It's easy enough to read, merges by non-engineers are *far* better than JSON (seriously, don't use JSON, it's a horrible format for on-disk permanent data), XML's flexible enough to deal with evolving formats, and there's a buttload of common tools and libraries for working with it. XML is the hands down winner, no question, in my book.

There are some other formats that are nearly as good at XML on the first three points (YAML, Human-JSON, etc.) but they mostly all fail on the fourth point. Just stick to XML.

### Runtime Format

Here we're talking about the files loaded in by the engine at release time. For many engines, this is actually all the time, even during development: source assets in these engines must always be converted into a different runtime format.

1. Minimizing size, because disks are slow the smaller the data, the faster it loads.
2. Minimizing runtime transformation between the on-disk format and the in-memory format.
3. Safety from crashes or buffer overruns or the like if the data is retrieved automatically from the Web from untrusted sources, e.g. some types of mods in multiplayer games.
4. Avoid needing to resync all data on version updates, esp. for clients.

Much of the time, satisfying all of these requires some kind of engine-specific binary format. However, good serialized formats *do* work well here for some types of data. Item number 4 is particularly hard to solve with your own format but easy to solve with ProtoBufs or FlatBuffers or the like.